# Ansible: Iterate through captured command output

Tags: perl, ansible

I am trying to convert an existing Perl script to Ansible role. I facing trouble in iterating over a captured command output.

Here is the Perl Script:

```
# Description: This script will adjust the oom score of all the important system processes to a negative value so that OOM killer does not touch these processes ############


chomp(my $OS = `uname`);

if($OS eq "Linux")
{
  my @file = `ps -ef|egrep 'sssd|wdmd|portreserve|autofs|automount|ypbind|rpcbind|rpc.statd|rpc.mountd|rpc.idampd|ntpd|lmgrd|Xvnc|vncconfig|irqblance|rpc.rquotad|metric|nscd|crond|snpslmd|getpwname.pl|mysqld|rsyslogd|xinetd|sendmail|lsf|tigervnc|tightvnc|cfadm' |egrep -ve 'ps|egrep' |awk '{print \$8,\$2}'`;
  chomp(@file);

  foreach my $element (@file)
  {
    chomp($element);
    (my $process, my $pid) = (split(/\s/,$element))[0,1];
    print "($process)($pid)\n";
    system("echo -17 > /proc/$pid/oom_adj");
    system("cat /proc/$pid/oom_adj");
  }
}

else
{
  print "The host is a $OS system, so no action taken\n";
}
```

Here is what I have tried so far in Ansible:

```
---
  - name: Capture uname ouput
    shell: "uname"
    register: os_type

  - name: Adjust OOM to negative so that OOM killer does not kill below processes
    shell: 'ps -ef|egrep "sssd|wdmd|portreserve|autofs|automount|ypbind|rpcbind|rpc.statd|rpc.mountd|rpc.idampd|ntpd|lmgrd|Xvnc|vncconfig|irqblance|rpc.rquotad|metric|nscd|crond|snpslmd|getpwname.pl|mysqld|rsyslogd|xinetd|sendmail|lsf|tigervnc|tightvnc|cfadm" |egrep -ve "ps|egrep" |awk "{print \$8,\$2}"'
    register: oom
    when: os_type.stdout == 'Linux'

  - debug:  var=oom.stdout_lines
```

Now, I want to iterate over var and implement this part in Ansible:

```
foreach my $element (@file)
  {
    chomp($element);
    (my $process, my $pid) = (split(/\s/,$element))[0,1];
    print "($process)($pid)\n";
    system("echo -17 > /proc/$pid/oom_adj");
    system("cat /proc/$pid/oom_adj");
  }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. Below is the solution that worked for me. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out. Appreciate it :)

```
---
  - name: Capture uname ouput
    shell: "uname"
    register: os_type
  - name: Gather important processes
    shell: 'ps -ef|egrep "sssd|wdmd|portreserve|autofs|automount|ypbind|rpcbind|rpc.statd|rpc.mountd|rpc.idampd|ntpd|lmgrd|Xvnc|vncconfig|irqblance|rpc.rquotad|metric|nscd|crond|snpslmd|getpwname.pl|mysqld|rsyslogd|xinetd|sendmail|lsf|tigervnc|tightvnc|cfadm" |egrep -ve "ps|egrep" |awk "{print \$8,\$2}"'
    register: oom
    when: os_type.stdout == 'Linux'
  - name: Adjust OOM to negative so that OOM killer does not kill important processes
    shell: "echo -17 >> /proc/{{ item.split()[1] }}/oom_adj"
    loop: "{{ oom.stdout_lines }}"
    register: echo
  - set_fact:
      stdout_lines: []
  - set_fact:
      stdout_lines: "{{ stdout_lines + item.stdout_lines }}"
    with_items: "{{ echo.results }}"
  - debug:
      msg: "This is a stdout line: {{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ stdout_lines }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

below worked for me

```
- hosts: temp
  gather_facts: yes
  remote_user: root
  tasks:

   - name: Adjust OOM to negative so that OOM killer does not kill below processes
     shell: 'ps -ef|egrep "sssd|wdmd|portreserve|autofs|automount|ypbind|rpcbind|rpc.statd|rpc.mountd|rpc.idampd|ntpd|lmgrd|Xvnc|vncconfig|irqblance|rpc.rquotad|metric|nscd|crond|snpslmd|getpwname.pl|mysqld|rsyslogd|xinetd|sendmail|lsf|tigervnc|tightvnc|cfadm" |egrep -ve "ps|egrep" |awk "{print \$2}"'
     register: oom
     when: ansible_system == 'Linux'

   - debug:  var=oom.stdout
   - name: update the pid
     raw: echo -17 > /proc/{{ item }}/oom_adj
     loop: "{{ oom.stdout_lines }}"
```